# How can I look for a song from a javascript?

Tags: jquery, html, activeadmin, jplayer

I'm working with RoR, active admin, jQuery and this is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function () {
            pr_id = document.numform.profitable_route_id.value;
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                mp3: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-04-Lismore.mp3"
            });
        },
        swfPath: "js",
        supplied: "mp3",
        wmode: "window"
    });
});
```

But instead of load this song: http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-04-Lismore.mp3" i want to load a song from my computer, how can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to use a file input and handle the request either through AJAX or entirely on the server-side. JavaScript has no access to the user's file system.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! Could you explain it a bit more? I'm new on this.. Thanks

Comment: Google is your friend :)

Comment: Your computer as in *server* or *client*?